# What is the correct way with NPM to package a BUILT version of a forked Git repository?

Tags: git, github, npm, package.json, git-fork

I recently forked a GitHub repository to fix a problem, and created a pull request.  While I wait for the pull request to be accepted, I have pointed my local `package.json` at my forked repo, like so:

```
devDependencies: {
    "karma-mocha": "maloric/karma-mocha"
}
```

However it turns out that `karma-mocha` requires a build step to be executed to generate `lib/adapter.js` - a vital part of the package.  This file is listed in `.gitignore`, so does not exist in the repository.  The build step is a grunt task that is normally executed when the package is published to npm, so `adapter.js` exists in the downloaded npm module.

My question is this: what is the correct way to package a forked, built version of the repository so that I can use it as a dependency?  As far as I can tell, I have the following options:

1. Build the repository locally, create a `.tgz` file with the built files, then host this somewhere and point my package.json to that file.
2. Build the repository locally, alter `.gitignore` to allow `adapter.js`, then push to a branch on Github and use that branch as my dependency.

Either of these would work, but I feel like I am missing something.  Does npm have a concept of forked packages?  Not every git repository can be used as a dependency without some sort of build/dist step, so what is the accepted way to do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 8):

That seems similar to [karma-runner/karma-jasmine issue 38](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine/issues/38#issuecomment-47758742), not exactly the same library, but the same idea, and issue with adapter.js:

> As you correctly pointed out, `adapter.js` generated by `grunt build`.
>   `adpater.js` is placed only in npm repository when we run `grunt release`.
>
> If you want use your version of `karma-jasmine` then you can remove `lib/adapter.js` from `.gitignore`.

So option 2.